# Embedded Google Slides - changing slides will scroll the iframe into view

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, google-slides

I have an embedded google slides on a website.
When the top of the iframe is not visible ( not into the view because you have scrolled down ) and I use one of the buttons to change the slides or use the laser pointer - the presentation is scrolled into view, which is quite annoying.

Is there any workaround to prevent this behavior?

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-platform-qq73s) is a codesandbox example, scroll down so that the top of the iframe is hidden, then change slides/toggle laser pointer.

Comment: Why is this an issue? Why do you want to be able to change the slides without being able to see them?

Comment: Well, it happens even if just a bit of the top part of the presentation is not visible, when you can clearly see the whole slide. Some devices also have just enough height to display part of the presentation. Either way, we believe it's an annoying user experience to press a button that has a known effect ( changes slides ) but produces additional, unexpected one - scrolls the view